# How to stylize php "echo" result using css?

Tags: php, forms, echo

I have a contact form in my website. it works well. But, when we submit the form, there's a text appearing showing that the mail submitted successfully. I want to change the color of that text appearing...
The form has a BLACK background, the appearing text has also the same color. I want the text to be in White color...
What should I do?

Comment: *"there's a text appearing showing that the mail submitted"* - Which is what we don't **see.** - Post your code, or Google "how to use CSS."

Comment: just echo some html tags with your text like **echo '<p>My message</p>';**

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS code for your front text.

```
form#myFormID {
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Replace `#myFormID` by your form id.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<span style="color:#YourColor;">Your message</span>';
```

It should work